# Apache Spark encountering a very weird data-skew

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Environment: Spark 1.6.3, spark on yarn, 150 executors * 2 cores, 6 GB each (40% for memory), python.

I have a spark-Dataframe with 3 columns: {int('userId'), longInt('productId'), double('CatgResult')}, the dataframe has a length count around 1 billion.

The data has a characteristic, which is when a 'userId'-'productId' pair as the key, there exists at most only 1 another counterpart in the whole dataframe, and most of the 'userId'-'productId' pairs might be the only single pair across the whole dataframe.

Now here goes the codes:

```
# From HIVE, to dismiss other factors.
unionTable = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tempdb.unionTable")
# The problem.
unionTable = unionTable.groupby(['userId', 'productId']).sum('CatgResult')
# Any action.
unionTalbe.show()
```

whenever unionTable.action(), it was stuck at 'groupby().sum()' for around 10 min. From the spark web UI, I can see that in the total 150 executors of this stage: 
1. Two executors input about 200~300 MB, but shuffle write 2.5GB, which drag back the execution time; 
2. Other executors' inputs range from 900MB ~ 32B and shuffle write almost the same amount of data.

What's more:

1. I've tried concating each 'userId'-'productId' pairs into a string key, with str(unionTable['userId'])+"::"+str(unionTable['productId']), but it didn't help.
2. I then attached a random int [0,10] as the string suffix, didn't help too.
3. I turned the dataframe into rdd, with reduceByKey, skew still there, but with much more time to take.

In the whole program, this groupby() or reduceByKey() takes 95% of the total execution time, I don't have any idea what is happening.

My question is:
This data skew have severely drag back my program, because I am going to process trillions of data, and sometimes "shuffle output location missing" error occurs.. I have to find out what the problem is and how this data skew can be solved..

[image: Overview]

[image: The top shuffle output]

Comment: What's your questions?

Comment: My question is: This data skew have severely drag back my program, because I am going to process trillions of data, and sometimes "shuffle output location missing" error occurs.. I have to find out what the problem is and how this data skew can be solved..

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but this is the only skew related pyspark issue I know about: [github issue](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15389)